# To get JWT Token -getting 401 Unauthorized but working from Postman

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, resttemplate, rest-client

Can someone please help to understand if any wrong with the below code or what can be done to resolve the same? These services working from POSTMAN but getting error thru code

Getting error :

```
Exception and getting token :org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
```

Below is the services code, tried with URL encoding and also with ClientId and client secret encoding into base64, but didn't worked.

```
public class TestAPServices {
    public static String ChequeIssueCheckEndPointURL = "https://Cheque.com/accounting/api/Cheque";
    public static String ChequeUserID = "";
    public static String ChequeUserPassword = "";
    public static String ChequeIsAuthRequired = "Y";
    public static String ChequeSecurityType = "OAUTH2";
    public static String ChequeAccessTokenURI = "https://Cheque.com/oauth/token";
    public static String ChequeGrantType = "client_credentials";
    public static String ChequeClientId = "4YPC5FFFFFx0vsECzTft7Vyc6dVLdLJT";
    public static String ChequeClientSecret = "gHBp7YYYaAA7HGWn";
        
    private static void apChequeIssueCheck() throws Exception {

        String url = ChequeIssueCheckEndPointURL;
        String token = null;        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        if ("Y".equals(ChequeIsAuthRequired) && "OAUTH2".equals(ChequeSecurityType))
            token = getOauthToken();
        //....
        //service call
    }


    public static String getOauthToken() throws Exception {
        try {
            String url = ChequeAccessTokenURI;

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            
            HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
            HttpEntity<String> response = null;
            ResponseEntity responseEntity = null;

            System.out.println("URL : " + url + "\t GrantType : " + ChequeGrantType + "\t client_id : "
                    + ChequeClientId + "\t Client Secret :" + ChequeClientSecret);
            
            url = (UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)).build().encode().toUri() + "?" + Constants.GRANT_TYPE + "=" + ChequeGrantType + "&" + Constants.CLIENT_ID + "="+ Base64.byteArrayToBase64(ChequeClientId.getBytes("UTF-8")) 
            + "&" + Constants.CLIENT_SECRET + "=" + Base64.byteArrayToBase64(ChequeClientSecret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("URL : "+ url);

            response = restTemplate.exchange(url,   HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
            // failed here
            //... futher code to read token
            return  (String) ((JSONObject) parser.parse(response.getBody())).get("access_token");
        }
    }
}
```